# Poll multiple Repos using a Jenkins Pipeline and trigger job

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have multiple GIT repos lets keep it at 2 for simplicity, and I created a Jenkins Pipeline to poll those repos to check for new commits and trigger a separate Jenkins Job that runs a scan on that repo.

The issue I have with my Groovy script below is that its able to poll for new commits on either of the repos and trigger the pipeline but then it ends up triggering the scan job for both repos.

Here's my Groovy script for the Jenkins Pipeline

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        [$class: "SCMTrigger", scmpoll_spec: "H/5 * * * *"],
    ])
])
node {
  stage ('Trigger') {
    dir('ABC') {
      if (git(
          poll: true,
              url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/XXX/ABC.git',
              credentialsId: 'abc123',
              branch: 'master'
          )){
      build job: 'Scan', parameters: [
            string(name: 'Project_Name', value: "ABC"),
            string(name: 'Git_project', value: "ABC.git")
          ]
        }
    }
    dir('XYZ') {
      if (git(
          poll: true,
              url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/XXX/XYZ.git',
              credentialsId: 'abc123',
              branch: 'master'
          )){
      build job: 'Scan', parameters: [
            string(name: 'Project_Name', value: "XYZ"),
            string(name: 'Git_project', value: "XYZ.git")
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I added the IF condition but it still triggers the job for both repos, but I only need it to run for the repo which was committed to.

Comment: What about you put a Jenkinsfile in your multiple repositories and react to changes in them, e.g. with a Multi-Branch pipeline in Jenkins (jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch) ? And in the individual Jenkinsfiles you can call the Scan job with parameters or whatever you need. If you don't want to copy and paste too much, you can use a global library. And then, rather then polling every now and then, you only run the Scan job if really something has changed. You won't miss changes and you won't waste resources for unnecessary runs.

Comment: @Matthias I did consider that solution but in reality we have more than 70 repos and all of them are managed by different teams. So to add a Jenkinsfile in each repo I'll have to bubble it up and involve a lot of people which I want to try and avoid.

Comment: I might have some ideas. Actually I did not check your solution, but expect git poll to return true if it was successfull and nothing has failed. 1: configure your git server to send post-receive hooks to jenkins. The payload should contain the changed project. --> works on any agent. 2: use git commandline with `git fetch`. StdOut is empty in case there were no updates and vice versa. If you find a change, trigger your job --> requires a fixed agent and enough space to store all repos all the time.

Answer (score 0):

All your jobs are run because `git` step is returning object which always evaluates to true.
Actually, documentation says no poll parameter means poll:true, so you don't need it (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#git-git).
If you try this:

```
def obj = git("https://some-git-repo")
echo obj.toString()
```

you will see its content which seems to be a map:

```
[GIT_BRANCH:origin/master, GIT_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH:master, GIT_URL:https://some-git-repo]
```

If you rerun it however you will see aditional information which could be useful:

```
[GIT_BRANCH:origin/master, GIT_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH:master, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_URL:https://some-git-repo]
```

Now, let's commit to this repo and the result is:

```
[GIT_BRANCH:origin/master, GIT_COMMIT:1aac1ae15b7e872f273a44d4bf4ef5dc23cc19fb, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH:master, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT:1095fa8efbb96f2f63322be7b5a2e9d4d8988b5c, GIT_URL:https://some-git-repo]
```

A-ha! We can use this info.
Putting it all together:

```
def repoMap = git("https://some-git-repo")
if(repoMap.GIT_COMMIT != repoMap.GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT){
run-the-job
}
```